# XSockets IE, Flash web socket - [WebSocket] digest doesn't match error

Tags: flash, html, websocket

I've been playing around with XSockets, which is a wrapper for web sockets with  server framework and event handlers etc.. I've got the demo working in Chrome but I cant seem to get to work in IE.

I know IE doesn't support Web sockets but XSockets is supposed to handle this by implementing web sockets using flash if the browser doesn't support sockets.

I've stepped through the code and it appears to be setting up the web sockets dom correctly but I'm getting the following when it attempts to execute.

**console error:**

```
[WebSocket] digest doesn't match: \ÃYì}a[Ã«/
¢P != ²Õaå
YS:ó÷
```

Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen every time?

Sounds like there is a bug in either their server when it generates the digest, or in their XSocketsFlashBridge.swf implementation which I believe is just a re-packaging of [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js). If it happens consistently then I suspect it is a server problem since I know that the web-socket-js accept value calculation works (at least most of the time). Disclaimer: I wrote parts of web-socket-js.

Comment: Yeah it happens every time. If it's the server that's a problem then wouldn't the native implementation (i.e. chrome) of web sockets break?

Comment: @Mantisimo, I suggest raising this with the XSockets developers. They have contact info at the top of http://xsockets.net/Documentation